# Passing data between viewcontroller through property

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a dictionary on Viewcontroller A .I am passing it on viewcontroller B.On ViewController A it shows data on the dictionary of viewcontroller B.But ,In Viewcontroller it doesnt show any data in it?

**ViewController A:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell== nil) {

        cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    if(_List.count>0) {

        [cell setupCell:[_List objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        ViewControllerB *vc=[[ViewController alloc]init];
        vc.userIdInfo=[_List objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

**ViewController B:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"_userIdInfo %@",userIdInfo);
    if([userIdInfo valueForKey:@"UserID"]) {
        [self fetchDataFromServer:getdetail];
    }
}
```

This `NSLog(@"_userIdInfo %@",userIdInfo)` prints `null`. while  `vc.userIdInfo` prints dictionary

```
{
    Count = 3;
    UserID = "6gdab241-j176-1121-lde2-as8d21f62231";
    UserName = "abc@gmail.com";
}
```

Comment: where you are pushing your view controller to next view can you show me code ?

Comment: `ViewControllerB *vc=[[ViewController alloc]init];
        vc.userIdInfo=[_List objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`
after this the vc will be deallocated as you are not retaining the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In objective C, **cellForRowAtIndexPath** methods is used for showing the data.
As per code, you are intiallising the ViewController B in **cellForRowAtIndexPath**.
it will allocate  ViewController B multiple time which lead to memory consumptions.

I would suggest you to initialise in ViewDidLoad of ViewController A.

For Passing the data from A to B, you need to Use **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** method of UITableViewDelegate.

Example:

ViewController A:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell== nil) {

    cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}
if(_List.count>0) {

   //Use to show data

   cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormate:@"%@",[_List objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

   // [cell setupCell:[_List objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
   // ViewControllerB *vc=[[ViewController alloc]init];
   // vc.userIdInfo=[_List objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
return cell;
```

}

ViweController B

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   // 1st Type
   ViewControllerB *vc=[[ViewController alloc]init];
   vc.userIdInfo=[_List objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   [self.navigartionController pushViewController:aVC animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do ViewController B initialization in DID select method like below.

Don't initialize it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // 1st Type
    ViewControllerB *vc=[[ViewController alloc]init];
    vc.userIdInfo=[_List objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigartionController pushViewController:aVC animated:YES];

    //2nd Type
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    ViewControllerB *aVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
    aVC.userInfo = <set your data>;
    [self.navigartionController pushViewController:aVC animated:YES];

}
```

Hope this will helps.

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
 ViewControllerB *vc=[[ViewController alloc]init];
 vc.userIdInfo=[_List objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

only creates ViewController; it doesn't present it anywhere. moreover, the instance **vc** will be deallocated right after you leave the scope of

```
if(_List.count>0){}
```

your method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"_userIdInfo %@",userIdInfo);
    if([userIdInfo valueForKey:@"UserID"])
    {
        [self fetchDataFromServer:getdetail];
    }
}
```

will never be called, because your view will never load.

I assume, that what you really want is to present your vc instance with navigationController instance, or from current viewController

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController: vc animated: YES completion: nil];
```